# Are there any nontrivial examples of contradictions arising in non-foundational or applied math due to naive set theory?

Tags: logic, set-theory, big-list, foundations, paradoxes

I understand that naive set theory, whose axioms are extensionality and unrestricted comprehension, is inconsistent, due to paradoxes like Russell, Curry, Cantor, and Burali-Forti.

But these all seem to me like pathological, esoteric, ad-hoc examples, that really only matter in foundations, and most non-foundational and applied mathematics wouldn't go anywhere near touching them.

Am I wrong here? If we were to do non-foundational math over naive set theory and just ignore the paradoxes, what problems might we face? Yes, I know that we can technically prove $0=1$ because logic, but I'm looking for more interesting examples, particularly ones that could arise without having to specifically look for them.

> **Question:** Notwithstanding technicalities like explosion, are there any "natural" examples of contradictions arising in non-foundational or applied math due to the paradoxes of naive set theory?
>
> Has anyone ever arrived at a false statement in, say, algebra or number theory, using naive sets?

*edit*: I'd like to be clear that I'm playing devil's advocate. I'm of course aware that relying on an inconsistent theory is in general a bad idea, but of course not all flawed structures collapse immediately. How far could we go *in practice* before we ran into problems?

*edit*: By "non-foundational" I basically mean anything outside of set theory or mathematical logic. If the question of a theory's consistency comes up at all (this thought experiment notwithstanding), then it's probably "foundational". But it's of course fuzzy.

Comment: I don't get what you are after. Russel's set $\{x\mid x\notin x\,\}$ is about the simplest "set" that can be built using the naive methods, so using naive set theory as a tool for sets defined by properties involving more than three symbols cannot be trusted at all. - And all of todays non-foundatioanal or applied math is not based on naive set theory (or can be translated to set theories that are not obviously inconsistent)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm aware that "technically" naive set theory "can't be trusted". I'm asking a hypothetical question: Suppose history had gone a bit differently, and we were still basing all math on unrestricted comprehension. What would be the first signs of trouble outside of set theory?

Comment: I think this is a good question.  I was just wondering a similar thing yesterday.  A less controversial version of the question might ask "has naive set theory ever actually led anyone doing non-foundational mathematics into a contradiction?" rather than "is it okay to use naive set theory to do non-foundational mathematics" (to which most people would shout "no!")

Comment: On Trevor's advice, I've edited the title of the question to hopefully be less controversial and more reflective of what I'm really asking.

Comment: I somehow feel that my answer now is completely irrelevant. Should I delete it?

Comment: I personally don't believe in deleting whole answers just because they're "now ... irrelevant". I would just edit or something.

Comment: The experts here may disagree, but it seems to me that if you are working in number theory or classical analysis, the foundational issues were probably settled centuries ago, long before the axiomatization of set theory. In the course of your work, just be careful that any sets or functions you may define actually exist -- rarely if ever a problem in practice, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: Really, a set that contains itself or any construction that remains on self-containment is not natural at all! All those paradoxes come up if you let your intuition go und suddenly realize that the result is counter-intuitive. I call that a paradox of the human mind ...

Comment: @Marcel There are consistent (as far as we know) non-well-founded set theories though, so that can't be all there is. The deeper question is "just *what is it* about naive comprehension that is inconsistent?" Is it just these "big four" paradoxes, or is there something more general? *Where* is the ceiling exactly? I'm very fascinated by this; I could go on and on here. But this would be material for new questions, not discussion in comments on this one.

Comment: More generally, I want to examine how inconsistencies behave in math *as humans actually do it*, as opposed to how it behaves *theoretically*. That's the key distinction: Yes, explosion is a consequence of our formal system, but that's not how human reasoning actually works. We can't actually see every single consequence of a theory at once. We have to reveal them gradually via proofs. Even when we derive a contradiction, it's not at all immediately obvious what that would do in practice for the rest of the theory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With a strict enough definition of "non-foundational mathematics" I think the answer is probably "no" (although I would be very interested in seeing potential examples.)  However, this shouldn't make mathematicians working on such mathematics feel safe about using unrestricted comprehension.  The reason is that it's not always clear *a priori* what mathematics will turn out to be "foundational".

Indeed, people may start working on some mathematics that seems non-foundational but then turns in a foundational direction.  For example, Cantor's development of set theory was a natural consequence of his study of [sets of uniqueness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_of_uniqueness) in harmonic analysis.

If someone working in a supposedly non-foundational branch of mathematics ended up with a contradiction by using unrestricted comprehension, then with the benefit of hindsight we could say that he or she must have been working in an area related to foundations after all.

It might seem like cheating to make such a declaration after the fact, but perhaps it is not: It seems likely that, from a novel use of unrestricted comprehension to obtain a contradiction, one could obtain a novel use of replacement to obtain a theorem that could not have been obtained without replacement (*i.e.* using only restricted comprehension).  I say this because replacement is a natural intermediate step between restricted and unrestricted comprehension.

Mathematics that uses replacement in an essential way is often considered *ipso facto* to be foundational.  So I think it is likely that mathematics that uses unrestricted comprehension an an essential way (to the extent that it can be salvaged) would be considered foundational as well.

(This answer doesn't address the question of how long, on average, it would take people using unrestricted comprehension in non-foundational-seeming areas of mathematics to run into problems.  I think that question is very interesting but probably also very hard to answer.)

Comment: Good point - the term "foundational" is not very precise. I guess here I basically mean anything outside set theory and mathematical logic.

Comment: @BenW Sure, but the terms "set theory" and "mathematical logic" are not entirely precise either.  I think any definition of these fields as they are today should at least partly characterize them as the areas of mathematics arising from Russell's paradox and the closely related diagonal argument of Cantor, which would at least partly explain why they are the only areas (or at least the main areas) where "paradoxes" related to these ones seem to arise.

Answer (score 10):

The whole idea of using set theory as a foundational theory is that you want a theory that if you believe is consistent, the rest of mathematics is consistent.

Naive set theory is inconsistent. So you can't really continue, you cannot trust it to give you the rest of mathematics. And it is not important that you "don't seem to appeal to the paradoxes".

Axiomatic set theories, like $\sf ZFC$, come to make an effort to at least fight the problems that come up with naive set theory.

Why should you *really* care about the axioms of $\sf ZFC$? You shouldn't. You should care about the fact that $\sf ZFC$ is sufficient to develop basic model theory, and create the rest of mathematics inside its universe. And this makes set theory like the back-end architecture of your CPU. Do you really care that your computer is using an Alpha back-end or a SPARC back-end? No. You care that it is able to run Chicken Invaders, or YouTube, or $\LaTeX$.

Of course, if you are interested in mathematics, then you should learn at least a little bit how this processor works. Much like learning programming involves understanding the operating system, or the hardware design. So you should care because you want to know how your mathematics is being modeled, but in general you should care because naive set theory is provably bad for you.

Comment: But is it really "provably bad for you" if you are doing, say, algebra?  Can you point to an example of an algebraist who was unaware of Russell's paradox and accidentally "proved" an incorrect "theorem" in algebra as a result of this naivete?

Comment: Well, I can prove in naive set theory that $\Bbb Q$ has characteristics $2$. Is this bad enough for you? And once you start saying things like "Oh, but you can't use this and you can only use that" you essentially start to dole out axioms and get into axiomatic set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you link to that proof? Or write it down yourself of course.

Comment: @user2520938: It's just an application of the principle of explosion. Contradiction proves everything. :-) I know it's somewhat "cheating" but axiomatic set theory is exactly how we gave a list of rules which forbade that sort of cheating.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Haha oh yea of course.

Comment: No, I don't think that's bad enough -- you were only able to do it because you knew about Russell's paradox and were using it on purpose.  The OP was asking about what happens if we *ignore* the paradox.  My point is that the claim "naive set theory is bad for you" (unlike the claim "naive set theory is inconsistent") is a statement about human mathematical practice, so it should be supported with evidence about human mathematical practice.

Comment: @Trevor: I guess that this is something we'll have to disagree on. Because I think that it is a sufficient reason. I will try to come up with an example that will satisfy you. However if you insist that mathematics stays in the domain of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, then I'm probably come empty handed. Axiomatic set theory gave us more power and ease to venture into "every ring such and such" or "every topological space such and such", which go far beyond that cardinality of the continuum and its power set.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I see what you're saying, but I think it's unlikely you'll find a 'simple enough/everyday'-false-proof, for if they were so easy to come up with then most likely all of naive set theory would easily and intuitively be seen to be contradictionary, which it isn't.

Comment: @user2520938 That's a good point; another way to phrase the question (which Asaf might like better) would be "is there a mathematically natural-seeming way to prove the inconsistency of naive set theory?"

Comment: @Asaf I'm not sure that we actually disagree, but we can agree to disagree about whether or not we disagree, instead of (or in addition to) our original (dis)agreement.  In any case, a mathematically natural example would be interesting.  (I'm not sure it would have much to do with what rank of sets are "natural" to consider, though; I think it would have more to do with finding a more "natural" formula to apply unrestricted comprehension to.)

Comment: @Trevor: That sounds like a very set theoretic thing to say. In any case, I think that you are asking good, but nearly impossible questions in the comments (to both answers). We didn't use naive set theory for very long. We quickly ran into the paradoxes and quickly learned to avoid them. So even later arguments in mathematics which can be "formalized" in naive set theory are such that avoid the paradoxes of naive set theory. So I don't quite know what to tell you.

Comment: @TrevorWilson The whole enterprise of mathematical foundations only exists because there is the intuition that there is no "natural-seeming" way to prove the inconsistency of naïve set theory. I think if there were, we would have long ago given up on rigour.

Comment: @ZhenLin  I would guess differently; I think that if there were a "natural-seeming" way to prove the inconsistency of naive set theory, then we would have trimmed down the theory in a different way and the trend toward increasing rigour would have continued anyway.  (Also, we might have needed to adjust our intuitive notion of "natural-seeming".)

Comment: Suppose you discovered a "natural-seeming" inconsistency in, say, Peano arithmetic. Then the only way to recover would be to reject some "natural-seeming" principle – most likely unrestricted induction. But would you really be prepared to continue doing mathematics after you give up unrestricted induction?

Comment: @Zhen Lin: If you ask Woodin, he'd say no; if you ask Zeilberger, he'd say that induction is not that natural seeming to begin with. :-)

Comment: @TrevorWilson: I just came across this thread and your comment. It seems that the Burali-Forti paradox should satisfy you as a relatively reasonable consequence of human mathematical practice. Namely, the idea of well-orderings can be motivated quite easily by say defining the outcome of infinitary abstract perfect-information games, and we can prove that injection is a total order on well-orderings, so von Neumann ordinals come naturally as canonical representatives. Then naturally we consider the 'set' of all ordinals and find that it is 'well-ordered' under membership...

Answer (score 6):

I think:

- [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/35864) on MathOverflow is relevant.
- [This paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002220100197) is pointing out the counterexample.
- [This paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/73/1/65) is mending the original statement.

The theorem is in algebra, and is about whether the $\lim^1$ functor vanishes on Mittag-Leffler sequences in abelian categories satisfying certain axioms. In order to correct the mistake, the author had to add a smallness condition.

I also think that the non-existence of a free complete Boolean algebra on a countably infinite set of generators could be considered, though perhaps complete Boolean algebras are more explicitly "foundational".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't currently have access to those papers.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I wouldn't trust a building whose structure was *shown* to be flawed. Note that it isn't a suspicion, it is a certainty.

But I know what you mean by your question... consider the following "proof" (taken from another question at MSE):

**Theorem:** Let $K$ be a field, then $K$ has an algebraic closure $\bar{K}$ (i.e an algebraic extension that is algebraically closed).

**"Proof":** Define $A=\{ F \supset K | F \text{ is an algebraic extension of } K\}$ and inherit this with the usual partial order of inclusion. One can check that Zorn's lemma applies (union of a nested chain of algebraic extensions is itself algebraic). Thus take $\overline{K}$ to be a maximal element. It must be algebraically closed for otherwise there is an irreducible polynomial with root in some strictly bigger field.  $\blacksquare$

Do you trust this, as it is?

Comment: I "trust" it in the sense that it *is* a true statement, and the proof does not *immediately* pop out as being flawed. Of course I'm playing devil's advocate here, but this does show that not all flawed structures collapse immediately.

Comment: Do you have an example of how an algebraist using this type of flawed argument to prove algebraic results might accidentally fall into contradiction?

Comment: Hey the same "proof" shows that there exists a maximal ordinal!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, if you are talking about ordinals.  So it's not clear that such a contradiction would actually turn up while doing algebra.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Just because a flawed method can produce proof for statements that we know to be true (and can prove false statements in other situations) does nt make it a valid tool for the "true" case. Compare this with a beginner student proving an exercise by all weird combinations of using $\Rightarrow$ in place of $\Leftarrow$ or dividing by zero. Just because the statement finally "proven" is true (otherwise the exercise would not have been posed as such) this does not justify the student's erroneous attempts.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm not saying that naive set theory is "valid", or "justified".  Philosophically and mathematically, it's not.  But even so, one might ask: what happens if we use it to do, say, algebra?  Has anyone ever accidentally obtained an incorrect result in this way?

Comment: Could you explain exactly how this argument fails? I suppose it has to do with the fact that the collection of all fields is too big to be a set...

Comment: @A.P.: Zorn's lemma doesn't apply for proper classes. Essentially it works here since the "height" of this partial order is bounded, so we can extract a set which suffice for representing all the possible algebraic extensions up to isomorphism, and then apply Zorn's llama.

Comment: Also, the example has the following issue. $A$, if its elements are considered up to isomorphism, is not too big so as to be a proper class. Every algebraic extension of $K$ is either no bigger than $K$ or is at most countable, so $A$ 'embeds' in either $2^{|K|}$ or $2^\omega$, whichever is bigger. Ignoring these issues produces a "proof" that still captures the underlying point, and so I prefer it to the other standard proofs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a counterintuitive counterexample from the theory of inverse problems of a non-measurable conductivity on a disc that is not distinguishable from a homogeneous one w/boundary circle electrical measurements. It involves a function $f(r):[0,1]\rightarrow R^+$, such that $f(r^n)=f(r)$ for all natural numbers $n$. The construction of such a function involes a non-measurable set and the Axiom of choice. The inverse problems are relatively applied mathematics w/apllications e.g. to medical imaging.

Comment: How easy would it be to run into a contradiction if one were to base this theory on naive sets? Presumably this would be possible if you played with it long enough. (Again, invoking the famous paradoxes directly doesn't count, i.e. you can't just say "Consider inverse problems of a non-measurable conductivity... Let $R = \{x | x \notin x\}$..." While that is a "valid" proof, it's rather trivial. I'm looking for more interesting examples.)

Comment: Well, there is a principle of no loss of information in physics, e.g. information is not lost inside a black hole, it is spread on its horizon.  But my counterexample w/non-measurable medium/function contradicts the principle.

Comment: But does that prove that naive set theory is inconsistent?

Comment: Well, it may imply that the set theory w/Axiom of choice is inconsistent w/the laws of physics.

Comment: But who cares about that?

Comment: Was not that your question?